# CSS equivalent of a numbered list from Microsoft Word

Tags: css, html

In Microsoft Word, and undoubtedly most other (modern) word processors, you can have a "list" of items (I use the term "list" loosely here), with a hanging initial character(s), and then insert a TAB to force the first character of actual text to align with your left margin of the block.  E.g. if I had a bunch of symbols as identifiers, I could have:

```
#    Foo bar on a long line
     Where this is part of the "#" symbol identifier above
%%   And this is a new line broken over many lines, but the
     left-most edge still aligns
$__$ Isn't that fine?
```

I am trying to perform a similar action in HTML5 using CSS.  I've found out about indents, a la:

```
<p style="padding-left: 100px; text-indent: -100px"># Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam lectus dolor, ultrices at euismod eu, dapibus sit amet mauris. Etiam maximus pulvinar sollicitudin.</p>
```

However, while the paragraph is left with a hanging indent, the first character of significance ("L" in "Lorem") does not align with the first character of significance when the line wraps.  For example, it comes out like this:

```
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Aliquam lectus dolor, ultrices at euismod eu, dapibus
    sit amet mauris. Etiam maximus pulvinar sollicitudin.
```

When I want it to come out like so:

```
# Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Aliquam lectus dolor, ultrices at euismod eu, dapibus
  sit amet mauris. Etiam maximus pulvinar sollicitudin.
```

Looking further I found out about hanging-punctuation, but this does not seem to be supported anywhere; moreover, it is specific to punctuation marks - what if I want to use a letter instead of a symbol?

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, @Scott and @Mi-Creativity.  I never knew of the `before` selector; it will definitely be used now that I know of it!

Answer (score 1):

This could be done a few different ways.

One method would be to use the `::before` pseudo selector in CSS.

```css
p { 
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px; /* added just to move snippit away from window edges. */ }


/* this applies to all p tags */
p::before { 
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px; /* moves character on top of left margin, away from text */  }


/* below merely inserts a character based on the class of the p tag */
p.hash::before {  content: '#';  }

p.bang::before {  content: '!';  }

p.huh::before {  content: '?';  }

p.dbl::before {  content: "%%"; }

p.law::before {  content: "§"; }
```

```html
<p class="hash">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>

<p class="bang">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>

<p class="huh">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>

<p class="dbl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>

<p class="law">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1087910/scott) mentioned in his good answer, this could be achieved in few different ways, so alternatively you may do it by using a `span` with `position:absolute` and zero `left`, and a combination of `margin-left` and `padding-left` to form the gap, something like this:

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ebdw6h62/)

```css
p{
  margin-left:10px;
  padding-left:40px;
  position:relative;
}
p .symbols{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="symbols">#</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>

<p><span class="symbols">!</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>

<p><span class="symbols">^_^</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.</p>

<p><span class="symbols">%%</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

<p><span class="symbols">$$</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
```